# Protobuf-net.Grpc generic services

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, protobuf-net

I've got a few gRPC services that all share a common method and was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
[Service]
public interface IVehicleReloader<T> where T : IVehicle
{
    public ValueTask<T> ReloadInstance(ReloadInstanceRequest path);
}

[Service]
public interface ICarService : IVehicleReloader<Car>
{
...
}

[Service]
public interface IMotorbike : IVehicleReloader<Motorbike>
{
...
}
```

But this won't even compile, it straight up says `The gRPC service cannot be generic.`

Is there any other way of achieving this, short of having to declare the method on each of the interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ties into some topics that have been discussed in the repo about *flattening* services. The following is implemented via [PR 206](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/pull/206/) (not by me - contributed from a user), and will be deployed shortly:

```cs
[SubService] // naming is hard
public interface IVehicleReloader<T> where T : IVehicle
{
    public ValueTask<T> ReloadInstance(ReloadInstanceRequest path);
}

[Service]
public interface ICarService : IVehicleReloader<Car>
{
...
}

[Service]
public interface IMotorbike : IVehicleReloader<Motorbike>
{
...
}
```

Here the `[SubService]` means that `IVehicleReloader<T>` is not treated as a service itself, but instead: those members are folded into the `[Service]` types where they are discovered, ergo: `ReloadInstance` appears directly in `ICarService` and `IMotorbike`, and is routed appropriately.

I'd love to get this shipped - it is a matter of time, priorities, etc.

Comment: Know this is probably asking a bit much, but any idea at all when this might be implemented? :D

Comment: @JohnUbuntu what I *need* is infinite time; in the absence of that, I have to do some kind of basic demand-based-prioritisation; I don't think this is a huge piece of work, but I haven't gotten to it yet; the git topic is here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/859 ; knowing that someone else needs it is useful info. Right now, my priority is AOT, which needs some love. If this has business value to you / your employer, I also wouldn't rule out some kind of (very modest) feature sponsorship - just sayin'

Comment: @JohnUbuntu see update